# What can cause a Grails GORM save to fail after validate succeeds?

Tags: validation, grails, save, grails-orm

Immediately before validate and save I check my domain object:

```
class MyDomain ... {
    static belongsTo = [owner: AnotherClass]
    ...
}
```

The 'owner' is set correctly. Then I validate; it passes. Then I save; it throws an exception about order_id being null. It throws even if use `failOnError:false` in `save`.

This happens in an integration test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some code samples and the error you get.

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable here, but I have seen similar things. Try doing a domainclass.merge(), that solved my issue. Good link: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your instance is valid according to the constraints the save can fail, because it depends on the database. Imagine if you have:

```
class Person {
  ...  
  Integer age
  ...
  static constraints = {
    age nullable: true
  }
}
```

And an instance:

```
def person = new Person(age: 9999)
```

And in your database table the age of person can have as max value **999**. Your instance is valid, but the insert will throw an error.

The same can happen with foreign keys and operations that depends on triggers.